# Improving performance of django DB query

Tags: python, django, performance, sqlite

I'm using django/apache/sqlite3 and I have a django model that looks like this:

```
class Temp_entry(models.Model):
    dateTime = models.IntegerField() #datetime
    sensor = models.IntegerField()   # id of sensor
    temp = models.IntegerField()     # temp as temp in Kelvin * 100
```

I'm trying to get the last 300 Temp_entry items to place into a graph. I do that this way:

```
revOutsideTempHistory = Temp_entry.objects.filter(sensor=49).order_by('dateTime').reverse()[:300]
```

However, this query takes ~1 second.  Is there a way to improve this?  I've dug around and found that order_by is horrible inefficient, so I'm hoping that there is a viable alternative?

An alternative I thought of, but can't figure out how to implement, would be to run the query every 20 minutes and keep it cached, that would be acceptable too, as the data can be slightly stale with no ill effects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If [caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api) is acceptable it always should be used. Something like:

```
from django.core.cache import cache

cached = cache.get('temp_entries')
if cached:
    result = cached 
else:
    result = Temp_entry.objects.filter(sensor=49).order_by('dateTime').reverse().values_list()[:300]
    cache.set('temp_entries', result, 60*20)  # 20 min
```

Also you can set [db_indexes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-index) for the appropriate columns

```
class Temp_entry(models.Model):
    dateTime = models.IntegerField(db_index=True) #datetime
    sensor = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)   # id of sensor
    temp = models.IntegerField()     # temp as temp in Kelvin * 100
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey, two followup questions: is there a way to have the query run every 20 minutes instead of waiting for the request to check if it's stale? What does the db_indexes do?

Comment: Andy, db_index just creates normal database index, which will increase a query speed. However, this speedup is nothing compared to caching. Also note that such DBs like Mysql and Postgre has internal  caching of queries, but not sure about sqlite. According to the first question: yes you can using django command and something like cron or celery but I think this is not good solution

Comment: Thanks Alexey, using the indexes and caching the view is rendering in an acceptable amount of time

Answer (score 3):

Johnny Cache! http://packages.python.org/johnny-cache/
It works out-of-the-box, and it works well!

Comment: Good solution, though how good it is depend on your R/W patterns!

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to add some more indexes in your database. Use the django-debug toolbar to get the SQL of the actual query that's being run, and use the EXPLAIN feature to show what indexes it's using. For this particular query, I'd imagine you need to add an index on `(sensor, dateTime)` - do that directly in the database shell.

Comment: in another comment on this thread the OP asked a question about what an index does. I thought I'd point that out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you know your entries always have an increasing dateTime (i.e. the dateTime is set when the entry is created and not edited), then you don't have to order by dateTime as they will naturally be in that order in the database.