# Get data from one model to another Django/Python

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-models, append

I'm building an application with python and Django. I have several models but I need to get data from one model to another (the relation can be made with a SOSS (sales order number). I do have the logic to do that, but is not as efficient as I would wanted. It takes around 5-6 min to process the data.

My Model 1 has the relation number (po_number) and is related to Model 2 (there is called planning_number) It takes a lot of time because Model 2 has around 93,000 data lines.

This is my logic:

```
def import_withtimes(request):
    print "importando With Times a ots report"
    po_cache = list()
    for item in Model1.objects.all():

        if item.po_number in po_cache:
            continue

        withtimes = Model2.objects.filter(planning_order=item.po_number)
        for wi in withtimes:
            po_cache.append(wi.planning_order)
            item.wms = wi.wms_order
            item.status = wi.shipment_status
            item.aging = wi.status_date
            item.carrier = wi.service_level
            item.add_date = wi.order_add_date
            item.asn_validation = wi.asn_sent_time
            item.docs_add_date = wi.docs_received_time
            item.save()
```

My question is: Is there any way more efficient to reflect data from one model to another?

Comment: Hi, is your code meant to be run in routine or you run it manually una tantum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your `model1` and `model2` related by a `models.ForeignKey` field (relating `po_number` and `planning_order`)?  You can then use a QuerySet to get related objects.

What back end datastore are you using?  Does it have indexes on the relevant fields?  Have a look at setting the `db_index=True` option on the relevant fields in your model definitions (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#db-index).

Also see [Improving performance of django DB query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652950/improving-performance-of-django-db-query)

Comment: they are not related by a ForeignKey, Should I declare those as a unique key? and it will improve the relation?

Comment: Is there a 1:1 or 1:many relationship between Model1 and Model2?

Comment: Im using Mysql btw

Comment: Here you cna see withtimes = Model2.objects.filter(planning_order=item.po_number) that the planning number is the 1:1 relation between the two models, once is fould I get the data from Model 2 to Model 1.

Comment: You want me to share my models?

Comment: Hi, I would like to have an explanation on this matter. The code of @Deluq is generating new elements in model 2 by copying certain fields values of elements in model 1, right?